# How to count from different tables in sql using Nodejs display on html

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

I have an expressjs app of which I would like to count records from database in different or multiple tables and display the results on HTML on separate divs. The code is working with no errors but the issue is that I get the same result counted from one table to all the divs on my html page

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'test',
    password : 'test',
    database : 'test'
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    // Find count of users in DB
    var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM section1"; //count first table
    var q2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 FROM section2"; //count second table
    connection.query(q, q2, function(err, results){
        if(err) throw err;

        var count = results[0].count; //i want to count table1
        var count2 = results[0].count; // i want to count table2

        //send values to html in different divs as count and count2
        res.render('home', { count: count, count2: count })   
    });  
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server running on 3000!");
});
```

and my html code, the idea is display each count from a table on a separete div

```
<div class="container">
     <p><strong><%= count %></strong> others. </p>
     <p><strong><%= count2 %></strong> others. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The answer is bellow

```
app.get("/", function(req, res, html){
    var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM section1) AS count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM section1) AS count2"; //count first table

    let count, count2        
    connection.query(q, function(err, results){
    if(err) throw err;
    //count the results
    count = results[0].count; 
    count2 = results[0].count2;
    res.render('home', { count: count, count2: count2 }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        app.get("/", function(req, res){
            // Find count of users in DB
            var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM section1"; //count first table
            var q2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 FROM section2"; //count second table
    let count, count2        
    connection.query(q, function(err, results){
                if(err) throw err;
        
                 count = results[0].count; //i want to count table1
                
        
                //send values to html in different divs as count and count2
                  
            }); 
setTimeout(()=>{
            connection.query(q2, function(err, results){
                if(err) throw err;
        
           
                count2 = results[0].count; // I want to count table2
        
                //send values to html in different divs as count and count2
                
            });  
        res.render('home', { count: count, count2: count2 }) 
},4000)
        });
```

Comment: I tried the solution above but am still getting the same result. The result of the first count is displayed on count2. Icant get the count from the second table to html

Comment: Thank you I tried couple of times, I found the way what I should have done answered below